# How to make my search field to filter the images by Tag name ,when in the input field the name beggins with "#" sign

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a search input that filters the images by NAME , but now i want in the same input field when the word typed or the letter typed , begins with "#" sign the filter to be made by TAG name of the images 
But i need the "#" sign to now be taken into consideration , as my tag names do not begin with "#". 
Should it be made with RegEx , to be case sensitive , or there is simpler way ? 
Below is part of my code.

```
<div class="searchButton">
    <input type="text" id="inputValue" placeholder="Search by name or tag">
    <button onclick="goToPage(0,limit)" type="button">Search</button>
</div>
```

And my Javascript :

This is how my array of object looks like and the functions :

```
arrayPhotos= [{
        "location": "Photos/_DSC0150.jpg",
        "title": "Title001",
        "id": "image_id_001",
        "tag": [ "building", "city", "hotel"]
      },
      {
        "location": "Photos/_DSC0226.jpg",
        "title": "Title002",
        "id": "image_id_002",
        "tag": [ "fruit", "palm"]
      },
      {
        "location": "Photos/_DSC0442.jpg",
        "title": "Title003",
        "id": "image_id_003",
        "tag": [ "building" , "catedral" , "history"]
      }
    ]

    function goToPage(pageNum, count) {

    let filter = $("#inputValue").val().toLowerCase();
    let imgIndex = pageNum * count;
    goToItem(filter,imgIndex, count);

}

function goToItem(filter,imgIndex,count) {
     let imagesToDisplay =  getImageArray(filter, imgIndex, count); /// This is the function where the filtering is happening////
     const imgCount = getImagesCount();
     RenderPagingView(imgCount);
     renderImages(imagesToDisplay);
}


function getImageArray(filter, imgIndexStart, numberOfImages ) {
    let filteredArrayPhotos = [];
    let ofsCntr = 0;

    if ( numberOfImages <1 ) {
        numberOfImages = arrayPhotos.length;
    }

    if ( filter !== '') {

        const tmpFiltered = arrayPhotos.filter(image => image.title.toLowerCase().indexOf(filter) >= 0);
        for ( let arrayKey in tmpFiltered ) {
            const elem = tmpFiltered[arrayKey];
            if ( ofsCntr < imgIndexStart )
            {
                ofsCntr++;
                continue;
            }
            ofsCntr++;

            filteredArrayPhotos.push(elem);
            if ( filteredArrayPhotos.length >= numberOfImages )
                break;
        }
    }else {
        for (let arrayKey in arrayPhotos) {
            const elem = arrayPhotos[arrayKey];
            if (ofsCntr < imgIndexStart ){
                ofsCntr++;
                continue;
            }
            ofsCntr++;

            filteredArrayPhotos.push(elem);
            if ( filteredArrayPhotos.length >= numberOfImages ) break;
        }
    }
    return filteredArrayPhotos;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps something like this would be better:

```
function getImageArray(filter, imgIndexStart, numberOfImages) {
  let output = [];
  let searchByTag = filter[0] === '#';
  let searchTerm = searchByTag ? filter.slice(1) : filter;

  numberOfImages = numberOfImages < 1 ? arrayPhotos.length : numberOfImages;

  let filteredPhotos = arrayPhotos.filter(searchByTag
    ? image => image.tag.findIndex(a => a.toLowerCase().includes(searchTerm)) >= 0
    : image => image.title.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchTerm) >= 0);

  for (let i = imgIndexStart; i < filteredPhotos.length; i++) {
    output.push(filteredPhotos[i]);

    if (output.length >= numberOfImages) {
      break;
    }
  }

  return output;
}
```

Effectively, you want to define your filter function at the beginning, based on the value of your `filter` variable. If it is a "tag" search, then you set the `searchTerm` to be the string after the `#` using `filter.slice(1)`, otherwise you leave it as is.

You can greatly simplify your loop by using a standard for loop, to start the loop index at the correct position.

Comment: Works , thank you , but it does not show the other images that have partial of the word written in their tag names. For example if i type #cat , i get all the images that have "cat" in their tags , but not the images hat have "CATedral" in their tags. IS there a way to fix that ? And can it be done to search by one or more tags ( to write #cat #dog ) and to display all the images containing those ?

Comment: That should still work for tags with “CATedral”. Youre not calling toLowerCase on your search term though, so I would expect “Cat” wouldnt match, but “cat” would. Perhaps thats the issue?

Comment: Still not working , i think the issue is coming from the fact that in the console i get a message that `image.tag.toLowerCase()` is not a function . Do you see any particular reason for that , as when i remove .`toLowerCase()` it is working , but not with the full conditions i need. BUT on the `image.title.toLowerCase()` it does not say that it is not a function .

Comment: Sorry I just looked at your data again. Because tag is an array you need to check each item in tag to see if one matches the search term. I've updated my answer. EDIT: Updated it again

Comment: That was it , thank you so much James . You are awesome.

Comment: In your opinion , if i want the search by name and tag to happen with several inputs  ( #cat #car #dog etc. ) is it the best option to use RegExp ? Same goes for the search by name .

Comment: It depends on how large your array of items is. If it's going to a real performance bottle neck to run each image through several iterations then it might be a good way to keep linear performance, but if you've got less than maybe 1000 items, the performance increase probably isn't worth the mental overhead in code of constructing the dynamic regex..

Comment: Ok, I will try and figure it our with this code. :)

Comment: Hi again James, is it possible to make the search - multiple ? Li to write in the search field : #tree, #sunset   - > and  the result to be all the messages containing those tags? Currently it works only with one tag search .

Comment: @Jefry90 You should ask this in another question, as youre moving beyond the scope of the original question.